# Can perfect behavior be proved in a game of incomplete information?

Tags: game-theory

Assumption: We have a machine that plays games perfectly.

1. The machine plays a game of Chess. Chess is a game of **perfect information** and **complete information**. We (assuming we have enough computational power for that) build the complete game tree for a game of chess and show that every move the machine made was minimizing the possible loss for the worst case scenario (comparison to minimax) and as a result, prove that it was playing perfectly.
2. The machine plays a game of Backgammon. Backgammon is a game of **imperfect information**, but still **complete information** since both players have the same amount of information available to them. We do the same thing as with chess, including the dice rolls and probabilities for every possible outcome and show that every move that the machine made was, once again, minimizing the possible loss for the worst case scenario (comparison to expectiminimax) and as a result, prove that it was playing perfectly.
3. Now the machine plays a game of Poker. Poker is a game of **imperfect information** and also **incomplete information**. Once we're reviewing the game, can we mathematically prove that the moves the machine made were perfect? Or is the fact that bluffing as a concept exists already means that it's sometimes impossible to compare two moves with each other and decide if there was anything better that could've been done?

If not, does that also mean that the assumption is wrong and it's impossible to play perfectly with incomplete information?

Comment: What is the perfect play? Consider a finite two player game of perfect information in which player 1 can force a win. That doesn't preclude the possibility that player 2 can win and though all behavior of player 2 will be, vacuously, minmax behavior, there are arguably better and worse things to do.

Comment: Well if both players are playing perfectly then the player 1 will win every time. Or am I missunderstanding? Player two can win only and only if the first player doesn't play perfectly. Perfect play is, where you can logically and mathematically show that any other move is either just as good or worse implying that every turn the perfect move (or one of the perfect moves) was played. Simply take tic-tac-toe, you should be easily able to tell if some player played perfectly or missed a forced win/got forced into a loss.

Comment: "where you can logically and mathematically show that any other move is either just as good or worse" is not actually a mathematical definition.

Comment: It is absolutely not. Did you want one?

Comment: Depending on how you define perfect play, the answer can be yes or no.

Comment: Then I'd love to see both of the definitions that lead to the different conclusions! One definition that I have already mentioned in the post was - an optimal move is said to be optimal if it minimizes the possible loss for a worst case (max loss) scenario and an optimal play would be a play where every move was optimal. [1]  The 2nd definition which from my understanding is just different wording for the same idea - an optimal move is said to be optimal if it preserves the optimal outcome for all moves that the opponent can make [2]. 1 - Wikipedia, 2 - Sequential games and optimal strategies.

Comment: Are you only looking at two-player zero-sum games?

Comment: Yes, I probably should have made that more clear in my post

Comment: The minmax-theorem applies to two-player poker too.